# Elasticsearch querying string with value "NO"

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have string field with value CountryCode

When trying to query it with value "SE" works fine.

When trying with value "NO" I don't get any result while there are a few thousands.

Anyone have any idea why, I even use Kibana on this with the map plugin and nothing from NO is shown.

Comment: Is "NO" on your stop word list?

Comment: set the field that you are searching for word 'no' as `not_analyzed` otherwise by default it considered to be a stop word and it is not indexed as a term

Comment: note: in v1.0.0, the standard analyzer no longer uses the English stopwords list, for this very reason

Comment: can you please post the mapping of your index or CountryCode field ? And also few sample document with NO

Comment: You don't have todo anything anymore as they said stopwords are removed as default